# WP_list_table prepare_items()

Tags: wp-list-table

I create custom WP_list_table with side form like (adding new category form), but when i submit that form wp_list_table doesn't refresh. When I once again refresh page information appears.I use wp_list_table_example plugin everything is the same except for geting example_data and form.

```
 class TT_Example_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {

    function __construct(){
        global $status, $page;

        //Set parent defaults
        parent::__construct( array(
            'singular'  => 'movie',     //singular name of the listed records
            'plural'    => 'movies',    //plural name of the listed records
            'ajax'      => false        //does this table support ajax?
        ) );

    }
    function column_default($item, $column_name){
        switch($column_name){
            case 'rating':
            case 'director':
                return $item[$column_name];
            default:
                return print_r($item,true); //Show the whole array for troubleshooting purposes
        }
    }

    function column_title($item){

        //Build row actions
        $actions = array(
            'edit'      => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&movie=%s">Edit</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'edit',$item['ID']),
            'delete'    => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&movie=%s">Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item['ID']),
        );

        //Return the title contents
        return sprintf('%1$s <span style="color:silver">(id:%2$s)</span>%3$s',
            /*$1%s*/ $item['title'],
            /*$2%s*/ $item['ID'],
            /*$3%s*/ $this->row_actions($actions)
        );
    }
    function column_cb($item){
        return sprintf(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="%1$s[]" value="%2$s" />',
            /*$1%s*/ $this->_args['singular'],  //Let's simply repurpose the table's singular label ("movie")
            /*$2%s*/ $item['ID']                //The value of the checkbox should be the record's id
        );
    }

    function get_columns(){
        $columns = array(
            'cb'        => '<input type="checkbox" />', //Render a checkbox instead of text
            'title'     => 'Title',
            'rating'    => 'Rating',
        );
        return $columns;
    }

    function get_sortable_columns() {
        $sortable_columns = array(
            'title'     => array('title',false),     //true means it's already sorted
            'rating'    => array('rating',false),
            'director'  => array('director',false)
        );
        return $sortable_columns;
    }

    function get_bulk_actions() {
        $actions = array(
            'delete'    => 'Delete'
        );
        return $actions;
    }
    function process_bulk_action() {

        //Detect when a bulk action is being triggered...
        if( 'delete'===$this->current_action() ) {
            wp_die('Items deleted (or they would be if we had items to delete)!');
        }

    }
    function prepare_items() {


          $data = array();
        $example_data = array();
    $terms = get_terms( 'productcat', array('hide_empty' => false));

print_r($terms);
        if ( ! empty( $terms )  ){
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

         $data[] = array(
                            'ID'          =>  $term->term_id,
                            'title'       => $term->name
                            );

     }
 }

        $example_data = $data;

        $per_page = 5;


        $columns = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden = array();
        $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();
        $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);
        $this->process_bulk_action();
        $data = $example_data;

        function usort_reorder($a,$b){
            $orderby = (!empty($_REQUEST['orderby'])) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'title'; //If no sort, default to title
            $order = (!empty($_REQUEST['order'])) ? $_REQUEST['order'] : 'asc'; //If no order, default to asc
            $result = strcmp($a[$orderby], $b[$orderby]); //Determine sort order
            return ($order==='asc') ? $result : -$result; //Send final sort direction to usort
        }
        usort($data, 'usort_reorder');

        $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
        $total_items = count($data);
        $data = array_slice($data,(($current_page-1)*$per_page),$per_page);

        $this->items = $data;


        $this->set_pagination_args( array(
            'total_items' => $total_items,                  //WE have to calculate the total number of items
            'per_page'    => $per_page,                     //WE have to determine how many items to show on a page
            'total_pages' => ceil($total_items/$per_page)   //WE have to calculate the total number of pages
        ) );
    }


}


function tt_add_menu_items(){
    add_menu_page('Example Plugin List Table', 'List Table Example', 'activate_plugins', 'tt_list_test', 'tt_render_list_page');
} add_action('admin_menu', 'tt_add_menu_items');


function tt_render_list_page(){

    //Create an instance of our package class...
    $testListTable = new TT_Example_List_Table();
    //Fetch, prepare, sort, and filter our data...
    $testListTable->prepare_items();




    ?>
    <div class="wrap">

        <div id="icon-users" class="icon32"><br/></div>
        <h2>List Table Test</h2>

        <form id="movies-filter" method="GET">

            <!-- For plugins, we also need to ensure that the form posts back to our current page -->
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['page'] ?>" />
            <!-- Now we can render the completed list table -->
            <?php $testListTable->display(); ?>

        </form>
          <form id="insert_term" name="insert_term" method="post" action=""> 

           <div class="form-field  term-name-wrap">
          <label for="term">Term</label>
         <input type="text" value="" name="term" id="term" size="40" />
         <p>Description</p>
        </div>

    <label>Description</label><input type="text" value="" name="termdesc" id="termdesc" />

    <input type="submit" value="Add term" id="submit" name="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_term" />

</form> 

         <?php

if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_term") {
if (isset($_POST['term']) && !empty( $_POST['term']) ) {

 $new_term =  $_POST['term'];
 $description = $_POST['desc'];
        wp_insert_term(
          $new_term,
          'productcat',
            array(
         'description'=> $description,
        ));

    } 

}

?>        
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

My question is, when I add in the form new term why not refresh wp_list_table, is it because of the way of getting data or the way data is added.
How refresh wp_table_list after i submit new term. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You are processing the New Terms after you've displayed the Table List already, so in order to display the new term, as soon as you submit the form, you'd need to process it before you display the table.

I've added a new function `process_form()` in here, that handles the processing of new_trem form submission, so when the form is submitted, it'll verify the nonce field ( Which you should always use `wp_create_nonce_field()` ) and add a term.

Also, for page headings you don't need the icon32 div anymore `<div id="icon-users" class="icon32"><br/></div>`, you should remove this one.

And the page headings need to be enclosed in `<h1>` tags for admin screens since WordPress 4.3: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/07/31/headings-in-admin-screens-change-in-wordpress-4-3/

```
function tt_render_list_page() {
    //Handle New Term Form Submission
    $this->wpse_220820_process_form();
    //Create an instance of our package class...
    $testListTable = new TT_Example_List_Table();
    //Fetch, prepare, sort, and filter our data...
    $testListTable->prepare_items(); ?>
    <div class="wrap">

        <div id="icon-users" class="icon32"><br/></div>
        <h1>List Table Test</h1>

        <form id="movies-filter" method="GET">

            <!-- For plugins, we also need to ensure that the form posts back to our current page -->
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['page'] ?>"/>
            <!-- Now we can render the completed list table -->
            <?php $testListTable->display(); ?>

        </form>
        <form id="insert_term" name="insert_term" method="post" action="">

            <div class="form-field  term-name-wrap">
                <label for="term">Term</label>
                <input type="text" value="" name="term" id="term" size="40"/>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div>

            <label>Description</label><input type="text" value="" name="termdesc" id="termdesc"/>

            <input type="submit" value="Add term" id="submit" name="submit"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_term"/>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'wpse_220788_new_term', 'new_term_nonce' ); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Checks $_POST for Form submission and insert it into table
 */
function wpse_220820_process_form() {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == "new_term" ) {
        //Verify Nonce
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['new_term_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['new_term_nonce'], 'wpse_220788_new_term' ) ) {
            if ( isset( $_POST['term'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['term'] ) ) {

                $new_term    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['term'] );
                $description = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['desc'] );
                wp_insert_term(
                    $new_term,
                    'productcat',
                    array(
                        'description' => $description,
                    )
                );

            }
        }

    }
}
```